# Unable to click on button in Safari using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, safari, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on following button but When I run script button is not clicked still script is passing.

Here is HTML snipped

```
<input type="button" value="Authorize" class="standard" id="oauth2button" style="margin-left: 60px;">
```

Here is ruby code which i used to perform click operation

```
authorize_button = $driver.find_element(:id, 'oauth2button')
authorize_button.click
```

If I use `authorize_button.displayed?` it returns true.
I am using Selenium WebDriver and Safari version is 6.1.1

Comment: why does it seem to you that *button is not clicking* ? Any error or what else you found ?

Comment: More code is needed to figure out what is happening before the `click()`  call is sent.

However in most cases I have found that inserting a small sleep before the click usually fixes things. Try that and let me know if it makes any difference.

Comment: Actually I want to click on that button and it will open new window then in new window I am performing different operation.But what happened after clicking on above button window is not opened so all elements from new window are not found. Hence I commented all code after clicking on above button and check that script is passing but window is not opened I have also put sleep of 20 after click.

Comment: one more thing all my script is working fine for MAC Firefox, MAC Chrome combination but on MAC SAfari I am facing issue

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for but one thing I've done when I encounter that kind of problems is to use JavaScript to execute that particular action instead of Selenium, that has worked for me every time. You could try something like:

```
$driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('oauth2button').click();")
```

Comment: I have also used JavaScript to click on button in following way $driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", authorize_button). Its not working for me.